# package org.apache.pdfbox does not exist

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, pdfbox

I have a problem with my java project, when extracting the pdf (package org.apache.pdfbox does not exist)

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.PDFReader
import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
```

[image]

I've replaced add fontbox and pdfbox 2.0.26.. but there are still some errors, and extracting the pdf can't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RYiI.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you miss the needed jar in the classpath

Comment: Does you project have the required dependencies / libraries on the build path?  The compilation error implies that it doesn't.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the properties in Netbeans, or your maven file (if you use maven). If not maven then right-click on the project, then left click properties, libraries. You'll need pdfbox and fontbox 2.0.26. "PDFReader" is usually not needed, this is a stand alone application.

Comment: So this is 1.8.4 and the file doesn't even exist (maybe you "inherited" that project?). You should remove that entry and add fontbox and pdfbox 2.0.26, download the jar files from https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Alternatively, pdfbox 1.8.16 app also from the download link. But the 1.8 versions are really outdated.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8RcC.jpg)

problem solved,, I use java language,, I added pdfbox.app 2.0.26.jar and removed pdfbox and fontpdf 2.0.26.jar